# Struct in queue

Tags: c#

I have a struct like below:

```
struct Add
{
    public static string url;
    public static string password;
    public static string fake_path;
    public static List<string> upload = new List<string>();
}
```

From the form I fill all these vars. And then I need to add this struct to Queue. How to do this?

Comment: Why are all the fields `static`? Don't they belong to the instance? If you have only static members, don't use a `struct`; use a `static class` instead. But I guess your fields should be non-static. In a `struct`, a non-static field (instance field) can't have a field initializer, like `upload` has. Maybe you want a non-static `class`? Will your type (struct/class) be _mutable_?

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Add> queue = new System.Collections.Generic.Queue<Add>();
// queue.Enqueue(new Add(...));
```